# OpenGL Odd Row Fragment Shader Error: Not drawing

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm writing an application that renders every frame of in interleaved stereoscopic 3d. To make this happen, I am writing two fragment shaders: one to render the left eye's frame's odd rows, and one to render the even rows of pixels of the right frame.

I was using OSX's builtin OpenGL Shader Builder application, and I was able to successfully render every odd row as green:
[image: OpenGL Shader Builder odd row fragment shader]

As you can see, the frag code I'm using looks like this:

```
    void main(){
        if ( mod(gl_FragCoord.y - 0.5, 2.0) == 1.0){
            gl_FragCoord = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    }
```

However, I wrote a small OpenGL application to test this shader (Btw, this is NVIDIA OpenGL 2.1, OSX 10.6.8):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>


    #ifdef __APPLE__
    #include <OpenGL/gl.h>
    #include <OpenGL/glu.h>
    #include <GLUT/glut.h>


    void DrawGLScene(){
      glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

      glFlush();
      glutSwapBuffers();
    }


    void Shading(){
      //Fragment shader we want to use
      GLuint oddRowShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      std::cout << "Creating the fragment shader with id " << oddRowShaderId << std::endl;

      const GLchar *source[] = 
      { "void main(){   \n",
        "  if (mod(gl_FragCoord.y-0.5, 2.0) == 0.0){\n",
        "    gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );\n",
        //"    gl_BackColor = vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
        "  }\n",
        "}\n"
      };

      std::cout << "Shader source:\n" << source[0] << source[1] << source[2] << source[3] <       < source[4] << std::endl;


      std::cout << "Gathering shader source code" << std::endl;
      glShaderSource(oddRowShaderId, 1, source, 0);

      std::cout << "Compiling the shader" << std::endl;
      glCompileShader(oddRowShaderId);

      std::cout << "Creating new glCreateProgram() program" << std::endl;
      GLuint shaderProgramId = glCreateProgram();    //Shader program id

      std::cout << "Attaching shader to the new program" << std::endl;
      glAttachShader(shaderProgramId, oddRowShaderId); //Add the fragment shader to the         program

      std::cout << "Linking the program " << std::endl;
      glLinkProgram(shaderProgramId);                //Link the program


      std::cout << "Using the shader program for rendering" << std::endl;
      glUseProgram(shaderProgramId);                  //Start using the shader
    }

    void keyboard(int key, int x, int y){
      switch(key){
      case 's':
        Shading();
        break;
      case 'q':
        exit(0);
        break;
      }

    }

    void idleFunc(){
      glutPostRedisplay();        //Redraw the scene.
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv){
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
      glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
      glutInitWindowSize(1000,1000);
      glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
      glutCreateWindow("anaglyph test");
      glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene);
      glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
      glutIdleFunc(idleFunc);

      glutMainLoop();
    }
```

This is the output I get from running the code:
[image: Error Output]
I have a feeling I may not be compiling and `glUseProgram`ing the fragment shader correctly.

Comment: You're not doing any error checking of your shader compile and link, which is not good. You should be using glGetShaderiv/glGetProgramiv to query GL_COMPILE_STATUS and GL_LINK_STATUS after each compile and after linking, and if they don't come back as TRUE use glGetShaderInfoLog/glGetProgramInfoLog to see what it's complaining about. Also I'll not recommend doing equality tests on floats as you might get some rounding problems. See if you can reproduce `==1.0` with a greater/less than comparison that is tolerant of minor rounding errors.

Comment: thanks so much! I Implemented those functions now, and I found out it was a compilation problem. I seem to have fixed that, but now [I am getting this bus error when I try and run the program](http://i.imgur.com/gBJDz.png)

Comment: quick sidenote: the bus error is definitely being caused by the linker. Right now, I changed the code so that instead of creating a GLchar** array of each line of source, I just made it a single GLchar* and pass a pointer to it to glShaderSource(). Here's a gist of the new source file: https://gist.github.com/4069710

Answer (score 0):

Your can save some performance and gain some compatibility and it will result in less headache by using 2 pixel texture mask (even pixels are black, odd - white) and tile it on top of full-screen quads (you  will have 2 of them: right eye and left eye). Use inverted mask or put some coord offset on second  quad.  In general it will look like this:

(perspective and huge gaps added for visualization)
[image]

Put scene texture(or whatever you have) on quad and use mask color to discard fragments or [transparency](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm).  To avoid using 2 g-buffers (GPU memory) you can render a full scene for one eye in texture and for another in view and on top of it render full-screen quad with first scene texture and transparency mask. 
Or render them separate if you need two outputs.

---

Main point is that you should use masking instead of logic operations based on texture coordinates.